# d3js bilevel partition : Is it possible to update certain parts without exit & re-entring?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, graph, charts

I am currently using the d3js Bilevel partition because our data is too large to show all at once. I first had the sunburst partition with the last layers hidden with css, but then the chart wouldn't have the same size every time, which annoyed me.

A user can adjust values with a range slider, this should update the graph in real-time. This worked using this in the **sunburst** partition

```
path.data(partition.nodes) 
                .transition() 
                .duration(1000) 
                .attrTween("d", arcTweenData);
```

Is it also possible to do something similar in the **bilevel** partition?

So basicly this [sunburst partition](https://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/477c1bfb081b783f80ad) but with the bilevel partition or only 2 rows showing each time(like the bilevel partition).

***FOUND THE SOLUTION***

I've finally found the solution, the bilevel partition uses the sum by default so doesn't update with the changes made to the value. Specifying the value again before updating did it for me.

```
path = path.data(partition.value(function (d) { return d.value}).nodes(current).slice(1));
       path.transition().duration(750)
           .attrTween("d", function (d) { return arcTween.call(this, updateArc(d)); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Bilevel is different from sunburst in the sense that although it reads and stores the data/nodes into a partition, it only displays two layers by using the "children" element. Sunburst displays them all (default children).

In your case, what you really want is to update/refresh the path data using transitions. This can be easily be done by calling the transition on the path whenever you want to update:

```
path.transition()
      .style("fill-opacity", 1)
      .attrTween("d", function(d) { return arcTween.call(this, updateArc(d)); });
```

You could make it update on an interval or place it within a function that is called whenever is button is clicked. If you're not updating the d values, but updating an external data variable instead; you could simply pass that new data value using a global variable.

```
function updateVisual(d,newData){
 path.transition()
  .style("fill-opacity", 1)
  .attrTween("d", function(d) { return arcTween.call(this, updateArc(newData));});
} // If d is updated, remove newData and use updateArc(d)
```

Note: This is assuming you're using Bilevel Partition